# d3: Data Distribution to Elements Based on Specific Field

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, filter

Is it possible to "distribute" data to each element(say circle) based on one field with d3?

So say I have a data set that has the following fields:
"name", "age", "from".

I want to create circles, and each circle will hold all rows that have "from"=="SOMEVALUE".

The d3 code will look something like:

```
d3.selectAll(".circle")
  .data(data)   // <- I want each circle to hold filtered data
  .enter()      // based on field "from".
  .append("circle")
  .filter(....)
```

I apologize if the question is poorly worded.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Right, I think doing that will only store one thing. 
So in the case I mentioned above, it will only store all rows with "from"=="USA" to one circle. 
But what I really want is to store all rows with "from"=="USA" in one circle, "from"=="Taiwan" in another circle, "from"=="Great Britain" in yet another circle....etc.
Sorry that I didn't ask the question clearly enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the data before d3-binding it, using native array's `.filter()`. Like this:

```
d3.selectAll(".circle")
  .data(data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.from == 'SOMEVALUE'
  })
  .enter()      // based on field "from".
  .append("circle")
```